# When did the concept of 'isnad' originate?

Tags: hadith, history, uloom-al-hadith, isnad

In the history of hadith sciences, who was the first scholar to grade an isnad? When was the first use of the concept?

Comment: you want to know when the first chain was written or when the first chain was  graded?

Comment: @Hisham I want to know the origin of the concept that hadith could be evaluated by analyzing their chains of transmission.

Comment: I would imagine thats something that was invented when the first humans listened to the first liar among them

Comment: @Hisham Who was the first Islamic scholar to judge hadith by this concept?

Comment: The concept was already suggested by the prophet himself and the qur'an tells to check the verity of statements. Further the need for this came when people started fabricating hadith and spreading it to people who didn't have an expertise on the topic.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Where does he say this?

Comment: See for example "Narrated Abdullah ibn Abbas:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: You hear (from me), and others will hear from you; and people will hear from them who heard from you." ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3659)). But I had in mind another narration which I can't find at the moment.